# How to pass arguments into event listener function in flex/actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, events, arguments

Since when using sql lite if you try and do a function at the same moment it throws an error, im just trying to make a function that will check if its executing, and if it is try again in 10 milliseconds, this exact function works fine if i dont have to pass any arguments to the function but im confused how I can pass the vars back into the function it'll be executing.

I want to do:

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, saveChat(username, chatBoxText));
```

But it will only allow me to do:

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, saveChat);
```

It gives me this compile error:

> **1067:** Implicit coercion of a value of
>   type void to an unrelated type
>   Function

How can I get this to pass this limitation?

Here's what I've got:

```
public function saveChat(username:String, chatBoxText:String, e:TimerEvent=null):void
{
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(10, 1);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, saveChat);

    if(!saveChatSql.executing)
    {
        saveChatSql.text = "UPDATE active_chats SET convo = '"+chatBoxText+"' WHERE username = '"+username+"';";
        saveChatSql.execute();
    }
    else timer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A function called by a listener can only have one argument, which is the event triggering it.

> **`listener:Function`** — The listener function that processes the event.
>   This function must accept an Event
>   object as its only parameter and must
>   return nothing, as this example
>   shows:
>
> `function(evt:Event):void`
>
> [Source](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29)

You can get around this by having the function called by the event call another function with the required arguments:

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _saveChat);
function _saveChat(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    saveChat(arg, arg, arg);
}

function saveChat(arg1:type, arg2:type, arg3:type):void
{
    // Your logic.
}
```

Another thing you can do create a custom event class that extends `flash.events.Event` and create properties that you need within.

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEvent extends Event
    {
        // Your custom event 'types'.
        public static const SAVE_CHAT:String = "saveChat";

        // Your custom properties.
        public var username:String;
        public var chatBoxText:String;

        // Constructor.
        public function CustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false):void
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can dispatch this with properties defined:

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, _saveChat);
function _saveChat(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var evt:CustomEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.SAVE_CHAT);

    evt.username = "Marty";
    evt.chatBoxText = "Custom events are easy.";

    dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

And listen for it:

```
addEventListener(CustomEvent.SAVE_CHAT, saveChat);
function saveChat(e:CustomEvent):void
{
    trace(e.username + ": " + e.chatBoxText);
    // Output: Marty: Custom events are easy.
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually, you **can** pass additional parameters to an event listener without creating a custom event by using Actionscript's dynamic function construction.

```
private function addArguments(method:Function, additionalArguments:Array):Function
{
  return function(event:Event):void {method.apply(null, [event].concat(additionalArguments));}
}
```

When setting up the closeHandler for the Alert window we call the addArguments() method and pass in an array continaing all of the parameters we want to pass to the closeHandler. The addHandler() method will return the function we will call when the Alert window closes with the parameters included.

```
protected function btnOK_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  Alert.show("Would you like to reverse the text you just entered?", "", Alert.YES | Alert.NO, null, addArguments(alertCloseHandler, [txtInput.text]), null, Alert.YES);
  txtInput.text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 10):

> **1067:** Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type Function

Pay due attention to the error you got: it says that a `Function` is a type and that `addEventListener()` wants it. Although your listener returns void, it is a `Function`! So, what about returning **the listener**?

```
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, saveChat(username, chatBoxText));
function saveChat(username:String, chatBoxText:String):Function {
  return function(e:TimerEvent):void {
    // Do everything that uses "e", "chatBoxText" and "username" here!
  };
}
```

Simple like this. It works for any kind of event. **And no closure issues.**

**Note on `removeEventListener()`:**

Don't try to do `timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, saveChat(username, chatBoxText))`. It won't recognize your function because you'll be passing a new one on it every time you use `saveChat()`. Instead, just take its reference out into a variable and you're done:

```
var functionSaveChat:Function = saveChat(username, chatBoxText);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, functionSaveChat);
//trace(timer.hasEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER));
timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, functionSaveChat);
//trace(timer.hasEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER));
```

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful. Thanks! I never saw this possibility commented. Is there any downside to using this? Maybe there is some memory leak or something like that?

Comment: @OMA I've been fine for years with this. If you want to make sure, test it with a [memory profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872687/actionscript-3-profiler-memory-analysis-tool).

Comment: Great, thank you. In my case, instaed of saving the reference to the function in a variable, like you suggested, I'm using event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MyListener, arguments['callee']); to remove the listener from inside the function.

Comment: In my case I switch between both ways you guys use. Primarily arguments.callee is the way to go for simplicity. But when I can't remove the listener from itself then I resort to the reference in a variable. Both great.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var timerHandler:Function = function (event:TimerEvent):void
{
   saveChat(username,chatBoxText,event);
}

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Above calling saveChat(arg, arg, arg) it's not for me, i need to pass arguments that i dont have in this method but i have another solution

Im always using additional method passParameters to adding new arguments:

```
public function passParameters(method:Function,additionalArguments:Array):Function
{return function(event:Event):void{
    method.apply(null, [event].concat(additionalArguments));}
}
```

explanation of this is here - its simple and always work
http://sinfinity.pl/blog/2012/03/28/adding-parameters-to-event-listener-in-flex-air-as3/