# Custom Flash/Flex Event object

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, events

I'm in a Flex Mobile application project. I need to dispatch an event to the FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication and it has to contain a custom message.

I'm trying to make an object and dispatch it like this:

```
//create the event Object

var receivedObjMsg:Object = new Object();
receivedObjMsg.name = "receivedMessage";
receivedObjMsg.message = messagevarhere;

FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(receivedObjMsg);
```

and then receive it like this on the other view like this:

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener("receivedMessage", receiveMsgHandler);


protected function receiveMsgHandler(event:Event):void
{
trace("IT WORKED!");
}
```

But its saying it cant make an object into an event:

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@5a507911 to flash.events.Event.
```

I also tried putting this in the bottom of the main application mxml where i created the event;

```
<fx:Metadata>
[Event(name="receivedMessage", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>
```

I can't really seem to find an example that demonstrates what im trying to do. Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dispachEvent()` only accepts an `Event` object. You'll need to make your own class `ReceivedObjMsg`.

Details on creating your own class in an answer on a [previous question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406957/how-to-pass-arguments-into-event-listener-function-in-flex-actionscript/6407128#6407128).

Your issue is basically here:

```
var receivedObjMsg:Object = new Object();
receivedObjMsg.name = "receivedMessage";
receivedObjMsg.message = messagevarhere;

FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(receivedObjMsg);
```

Parsing `Object` through `dispatchEvent()`

Comment: I knew I saw it somewhere but I couldn't remember where i read it, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

`dispatchEvent` takes an `Event`

Create your own class that extends `Event` and then dispatch that.

Take a look at [this article](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/createevents_3.html) that discusses how to dispatch a custom event.

```
class MyOwnEvent extends Event
{
    public static const RECEIVED_EVENT:String = "receivedEvent";
    public string name;
    public string message;

    public MyOwnEvent (type:String, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {

    }

}
```

And when you want to dispatch it.

```
var myevent:MyOwnEvent = new MyOwnEvent(MyOwnEvent.RECEIVED_EVENT);
myevent.name = "whatever";
myevent.message = "another whatever";
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.dispatchEvent(myevent);
```

From the topLevelApplication, make sure that you listen for the same event.

```
FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.addEventListener(MyOwnEvent.RECEIVED_EVENT, receiveMsgHandler);
```

In the `receiveMsgHandler` take an object of type `MyOwnEvent`.

```
protected function receiveMsgHandler(event:MyOwnEvent):void
{
    trace(event.name);
    trace(event.message);
}
```