# How to pass values to eventlistener in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, parameters, addeventlistener

I am from a php jquery background and i am currently getting to grips with flash as3 just not sure how to pass values to eventlistner function say i have the following.

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++)
{                   
    asteroids[i].x = Math.random() * 450;
    asteroids[i].y = Math.random() * 450;
    asteroids[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, changeValue);            
}

public function changeValue(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    playSound(anote);
    trace(event.currentTarget);
}
```

each asteroid that i addeventlistner in the loop i need to pass a different value to the function the var anote?

jquery i would do.

```
$(".asteroids").click(function() {

     // or something similar 
     var anote = $(this).attr('href');
     playSound(anote);

     return false;

});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest making a class for your Asteroid instances (assuming that's what's in the `asteroids` array). Each of those Asteroids could have an `anote` property with different values (this closely reflects your `.asteroids` elements `href` attribute.

```
public class Asteroid extends Sprite
{
    public var anote:String = "";
}
```

And then:

```
for each(var i:Asteroid in asteroids)
{                   
    i.x = Math.random() * 450;
    i.y = Math.random() * 450;
    i.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, changeValue);            
}

public function changeValue(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    playSound((event.currentTarget as Asteroid).anote);
}
```

Ideally, your Asteroid class would also contain the code in your example and reference whichever class deals with the `playSound()` method.

---

The other option is to create your own event class with the `anote` property that you can set at dispatch and work with. The process is quite lengthy, so here's a link to one of my previous answers with an in-depth explanation of implementing that:

- [How to pass arguments into event listener function in flex/actionscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406957/how-to-pass-arguments-into-event-listener-function-in-flex-actionscript/6407128#6407128)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I've found is to create a function in the `addEventListener` line:

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++)
{

     asteroids[i].x = Math.random() * 450;
     asteroids[i].y = Math.random() * 450;
     asteroids[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(e:MouseEvent){
         changeValue(e, otherArguments);
     });

}



public function changeValue(event:MouseEvent, otherArguments:Object):void
{

    playSound(anote);
    trace(event.currentTarget);

}
```

Basically you create a wrapper function that can pass any arguments you need into the event listener function.

The other way to achieve this is to create your own class that extends `MouseEvent` and use that, but this is more complicated.

Comment: That anonymous function you're creating there makes me feel really uneasy. Also `Object` needs a capital `O` :)

Comment: This is a bad practice because you will get additional memory usage for holding wrappers, Marty Wallace suggest better way.

Comment: @Yarg I know this isn't such a great way to achieve the desired outcome, but it requires the least modification to the original code. I just thought the op would want to have a solution that fits in with the code he has, without having to make new classes or redesign.

Comment: It's good to know you can do what you've done in your answer, so there's valuable and relevant information there. I just wanted to note that it's not a good approach from a memory consumption angle - which combined with your answer provides a great avenue of information for a newbie in ActionScript :)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the replies i think ill try and write a class as i kinda want to stay away from bad practise, cause once i start ill always do it. Not sure how to do this ill try with the question below :)

Answer (score 0):

It's cumbersome to write a new class for the object or the event everytime, and it's unstable to use an anonymous function either. Just grab it in a variable:

```
var listeners:Object = new Object();

for (var i:uint = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {
  asteroids[i].x = Math.random() * 450;
  asteroids[i].y = Math.random() * 450;
  listeners[i] = changeValue(asteroids[i].anote);
  asteroids[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, listeners[i]);
}

public function changeValue(anote:Sound):Function {
  return function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    playSound(anote);
    trace(event.currentTarget);
  }
}
```

Then, to remove the listeners later:

```
for (i = 0; i < asteroids.length; i++) {
  //trace("asteroid" + i + " (before): " + asteroids[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
  asteroids[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, listeners[i]);
  //trace("asteroid" + i + " (after): " + asteroids[i].hasEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP));
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488640/1837285) on that issue too.